# How to remove index.php from slim framework URL

Tags: .htaccess, centos, url-rewriting, slim

i'm trying to remove index.php form an URL:

this works

```
http://server/bw/index.php/test
```

this doesn't work

```
http://server/bw/test
```

i try to change .htaccess and watching on web i see that it should be like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /bw/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

i try editing it in this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

or in this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /bw/index.php [QSA,L]
```

or in this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

But when i try to access to `http://server/bw/test` it says me:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /bw/test was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at server Port 80
```

I check that inside my `httpd.conf` `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` is enable.. i don't know what to do now..

how can i solve? please help me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, which used e.g. in WordPress

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

or this, which is used by e.g. Lavavel PHP Framework

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

You might also consider adding

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

before the RewriteRule to also exclude existing directories, not only existing files. But that's up to you.

Comment: nothing to do.. it doesn't works.. with both first and second rules

Comment: If you put these lines into a .htaccess file you should check if you have the directive AllowOverride set to All or FileInfo in your httpd.conf or the VirtualHost config because mod_rewrite needs this (see [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride))

Comment: i tried to set AllowOverride to All inside httpd.conf but when i try to go to the url without index.php it loads the index.php of the directory that is over the directory that contains the index.php of slim framework

Comment: btw. if you add the !-d RewriteCond you have to put it between RewriteCond !-f and the RewriteRule because they are only applied to RewriteRule immediately following.

Comment: then maybe you have another .htaccess file somewhere up the directory tree, most likely in the parent directory itself.

Comment: with this .htaccess RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] and with AllowOverride set to All it loads parent's index.php. In the parent directory there aren't .htaccess

Comment: ok.. it works :D i just edited AllowOverride to All from another part in httpd.conf. I was wrong before because i edited the AllowOverride of / directory :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I updated `AllowOverride All` , 
then run `sudo a2enmod rewrite` to avoid Internal 500 error then restart Apache `service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

For me, I got things to work using this line from Dehalion's answer:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

So the index.php (or any xyz.php) file is not seen in the request url

```
http://localhost/demo1/mycompany/hello/Jim
```

With the following caveats:

1. You have this route defined:

   $app->get('/mycompany/hello/:name', doHello );
2. The root element (for the route /mycompany/..) ***is also*** the name of the file.
   That is, the route exists in a file called "mycompany.php"

Yes, it's a bit of a hack ... but since I find apache config confusing/intimidating :) ... I figure this solution is stable enough to satisfy the requirements.