# How can I remove the index.php from url using slim framework?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, slim

I have this URL:

```
http://localhost:8082/sistemaTareas/api/index.php/hello/jean/bergeret
```

This prints:

```
HELLO JEAN BERGERET
```

I need to do the same, but with this:

```
http://localhost:8082/sistemaTareas/api/hello/jean/bergeret
```

I need config the .htaccess?

Edit: I saw the other answer, but did not solve my problem. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove index.php from slim framework URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225283/how-to-remove-index-php-from-slim-framework-url)

Comment: I saw the other answer , but did not solve my problem . Can anyone guide me ?

Comment: You might want to read this part of the doc : http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/rewrite/
Just make sure you activated the url rewrite mod in Apache

Comment: @JeanAndrésBergeretFuhrhop Let me know if you figured this out. If you don't, I'll create a quick slim app, and post my configuration.

Comment: @Jean: in what way did it not solve your problem? If you just say "it didn't work" then people will not know what further information to offer you. (Aside: please don't use upper-case writing on the web - it is widely understood as shouting).

Comment: @Yoluk I know where but, i don't know how config apache in centos. If you can do that to see the config , will be great.

Comment: http://docs.slimframework.com/routing/rewrite/

Comment: What is the content of your .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

I think a `AllowOverride All` is missing in you website apache configuration, in order to activate your .htaccess.

Your config file should look like this :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName my.server.name
        DocumentRoot /path/to/your/website/root

        <Directory /path/to/your/website/root >
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                AllowOverride All  <!--Here-->
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And your .htaccess like :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. It simply provides an alternative route to take. Whilst it is helpful, and may teach the OP a new way of doing things, it is better to actually answer the question being asked, specifically in the case of using this base URL: `http://localhost:8082/sistemaTareas/api/`

Comment: @MikeRockett I don't understand in what my post doesn't answer the question : In Slim, you redirect all the routes to `index.php` (which explains the `.../index.php/...` in the URL). You need to rewrite this URL with an `.htaccess` in order to remove it, and to do so, your apache config file needs `AllowOverride All`.

Comment: If this does answer the question (the part regarding `AllowOverride`, then the rest isn't necessary as it only shows an alternate way of doing things. As such, you need only specify where `AllowOverride All` needs to go. You are correct in saying that everything needs to be processed through `index.php`, but your code will not work for the OP, unless a virtual host is created, which is where the *alternate route* comes in. The OP is using *localhost*.