# htaccess URL Rewriting not working in PHP Slim framework

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, slim

Here is my `.htaccess` file code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /api

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

File path

```
api/
    - htaccess
    - index.php
```

This url was working fine

http://localhost/api/index.php/inventory/login/

But `http://localhost/api/inventory/login/` showing 404 not found error. How to solve this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225283/how-to-remove-index-php-from-slim-framework-url

Comment: I tried that but its not working. @AmitRajput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 
this in apache sites enabled file inside `<virtualHost>` tag

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

and `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```