# SOLVED)How to remove '/index.php' from slim framework url

Tags: apache, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, slim

My development environment is

Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS

Apache 2.4.7

mysql is 5.6.33

my directory is

```
/var/www/html/your-app
                   |--public
                   |-- .htaccess
                   |      `-- index.php
                   `--app
                       |-- src
                       |    |-- controllers
                       |    |       `-- WebController.php
                       |    `-- models
                       |            `-- WebModel.php
                       |-- templates
                       |    |-- main.html
                       |    `-- signup.html
                       |-- dependencies.php
                       |-- middleware.php
                       |-- routes.php
                       `-- settings.php
```

The root path of the slim framework works fine.

```
my_slim_url/index.php

my_slim_url

// load the same page
```

However, to move to another link on my main screen like this

```
my_slim_url/signup
```

this message,

```
'The requested URL / register_email was not found on this server.'
```

is displayed.

I've tried all of the answers on stackoverflow, but they didn't work.

Here are some my server's code that might be helpful.

If you tell me there have any problems or fixes that I have not found so far,

I would be grateful to your help.

I hope everyone to coding without error... :D

## apache2.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<ifModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</ifModule>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

## /sites-available/000-default.conf

```
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
 </Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/your-app/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

## /var/www/html/your-app/pulbic/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include your directory structure?

Comment: @phainix i edit my directory structure!! if you need more information, please tell me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove index.php from slim framework URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14225283/how-to-remove-index-php-from-slim-framework-url)

Comment: @LemuelCastro yea, i saw it already. but thank you for your seacrching :D!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I solved this problem!!!!!

## First, Run this fucntion:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

## Second, Check your's apache2.conf directory url:

```
 <Directory /var/www/html/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

it was, and i changed like this,

```
<Directory /var/www/html/your-app/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

## Third, Restart your apache service

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

then, it works!!!!

thank you for everyone to answered my question!!! :D

Comment: sudo a2enmod rewrite 
is very important to me :D

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Slim Framework user guide](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/start/web-servers.html#apache-configuration), your .htaccess (at `/var/www/html/your-app/public/.htaccess`) should contain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```